# Force quoteblocks inside tinymce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using tinymce wysiwyg editor to let people comment certain things, and I also want them to be able to quote each other messages in a simple way. It's hard for me to explain but I'll do my best.

I have an url that looks like `article.php?id=1&replycomment=1` and what it does it that it shows the article from the databse with ID 1 and let you comment the comment in the database with the ID 1. What I want it to do when I go to that link is that it would add `<blockquotes>` around the comment you want to reply to, inside of the tinymce wysiwyg. I shouldn't have to tell people to add blockquotes manually... it doesn't seem right.

Comment: you are getting the comment from server so add blockquotes to that comment on server side and then send it back to client

Comment: I tried it that way and it seem to work. Thanks for the idea.